# Conditionally perform an 'action' in do block

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I have a function like this:

```
myFnc :: foo -> StateT bar IO baz -- foo, bar, and baz are complex
                                  -- data structures
myFnc x =
    do result <- anotherFnc x -- anotherFnc :: foo -> StateT bar IO baz
    -- result is of type Either (= baz), now I need to perform
    -- an action only if result is created with data costructor 'Right'
    return result
```

I can think only of `case`:

```
case result of
     Right val -> ...
```

But `case` statement with only one clause looks strange... How do I conditionally perform an 'action'?

Comment: well there is [`when`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when) and [`either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:either) - but you don't really have only one case here - there is still `Left` - IMO your programm is more readable if you add the case and all can see that you just want to ignore it.

Comment: @CarstenKönig, Hmm.. you're probably right. I'll take a look at `when` and `either` anyway.

Comment: btw: I assume this is all in the `IO` Monad? You should add those type signatures ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig, well, not really it is in some monad transformer like `StateT foo IO bar`. Does it matter?

Comment: sorry - no, not really but it's nice to know what we are talking anyway

Comment: @CarstenKönig, I've written something like `case result of Right x -> ... Left _ -> ` but how do I do 'nothing' for the `Left` case? Sorry, if my questions stupid...

Comment: @Mark: Can't you just use `return ()` for the `Left` case?  (Also, it helps if you show what you are doing in your `Right` case.)

Comment: @Rufflewind, it should work! I should remember all these tricks after all :-)

Comment: @Rufflewind, I fear it cannot help here since the program is not small and in the `Right` clause I invoke just one function that changes state. But that function is based on lots of stuff, so I think it is not relevant.

Comment: @Mark: it helps if you at least indicate the type!  The `return ()` only works if the other case has type `m ()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case` is the right way to go but you need to handle all cases.

```
case result of
     Right val -> ... -- do some actions with val
     Left _    -> return () -- do nothing
```

A shorter alternative is to import [`for_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:for_) from [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html)

```
for_ result $ \val -> ... -- do something with val
```

However, your question is not clear on what you want to return from `myFnc`. Your signature has the type `foo -> StateT bar IO baz` but then you need to generate a value of type `baz` regardless of whether the `result` was `Left` or `Right` either by returning a common value after the `case` or by returning a `baz` value from both case-branches.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the library function `when` which has type `Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()`. If you also a function `isRight` which checks the constructor then you can do something like this:

```
do result <- anotherFnc x --
   when (isRight result) ...
```

Comment: Is `isRight` a standard function? Hoogle cannot find it. Should I write it myself?

Comment: @Mark: `Data.Either` has `isRight`, see: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Either.html